# How to add an already supported language in CodeFlask

Tags: prismjs

Hi I am using the micro code editor [CodeFlask](https://kazzkiq.github.io/CodeFlask/), I have configured it but I don't know how to add another language that is not JS.

The documentation explains about using flask.addLanguage('ruby', option) but it does not explains what **options** means. It also points to the [PrismJS documentation](https://prismjs.com/extending.html#language-definitions) but they also don't tell what options means.